# Record Video and Audio from Webcam with c# Accord .Net

Tags: c#, audio, video, webcam, accord.net

I'm trying to accomplish something easy as first sight: recording video and audio (from webcam) in an avi file using Accord .net framework. It appears more complex that it seems :)

So far, I handle video frames nicely (I think) with this frame handler:

```
void videoDevice_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imgforms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();

            //Using the freeze function to avoid cross thread operations 
            bi.Freeze();

            //Calling the UI thread using the Dispatcher to update the 'Image' WPF control         
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                pbox.Source = bi; /*pbox is the name of the 'Image' WPF control*/
            }));

            if (_recording)
            {
                long currentTick = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                StartTick = StartTick ?? currentTick;
                var frameOffset = new TimeSpan(currentTick - StartTick.Value);

                double elapsedTimeInSeconds = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
                double timeBetweenFramesInSeconds = 1.0 / 25;
                if (elapsedTimeInSeconds >= timeBetweenFramesInSeconds)
                {
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                    try
                    {
                        _writer.WriteVideoFrame(eventArgs.Frame, frameOffset);
                    }catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }

                    //Here come WriteAudioFrame(Signal signal) ?
                }

            }

        }
```

and Audio data is stored in a memory stream / WaveEncoder in the audio new frame event handler:

```
audio_stream = new MemoryStream();           
audio_encoder = new WaveEncoder(audio_stream);

void audioDevice_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Audio.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            audio_encoder.Encode(eventArgs.Signal);

        }
```

So now, I don't understand how to transform audio memory stream (or WaveEncoder ?) into Signal object needed to new method writted by @cesarsouza in last pre-release  v3.8.2 of Accord .Net:

```
_writer.WriteAudioFrame(Signal signal)
```

and how to synchronise video and audio. I suspect we need to get same amount of audio and video frames according to the samplerate.

Do you know any exemple how to do that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may use WaveDecoder

```
WaveDecoder decoder = new WaveDecoder();
Signal s = decoder.Decode();
_writer.WriteAudioFrame(s);
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer

Comment: You use WaveEncoder to encode sound bytes(signal) to the memory stream, so the bytes in the memory stream are encoded. to get the signal back from stream, you have to use WaveDecoder to decode bytes from stream back to Signal.